# Kotlin data classes: Why does toString() export private properties

Tags: kotlin

This Kotlin data class

```
data class PhoneNumber(val prefix: String, private val lineNumber: String)
```

has the private property `lineNumber`.

When I create an object:

```
val phoneNumber = PhoneNumber("0676", "123456")
// toString() = PhoneNumber(prefix=0676, lineNumber=123456)
```

I do not expect that the `toString()` function also exposes `lineNumber`.

In Effective Java, Joshua Bloch writes

> Provide programmatic access to all of the information contained in the value returned by toString()

If you won't do this, clients of your library will parse the `toString()` result to get access to `lineNumber`.

Does anyone know why Kotlin does not hide private properties in `toString()` in data classes as a default?

Comment: "If you won't do this, clients of your library will parse the `toString()` result to get access to `lineNumber`" - even if not included in `toString()` they could still use reflection to access the field value. I'd say that both approaches are the last resort and whoever is doing it must be aware of consequences (breaking encapsulation).

Comment: Perhaps the question should be, "Kotlin data classes: Why allow private data properties?"

Comment: I'd say `Effective Java` doesn't necessarily apply to Kotlin :)

Comment: I would suggest opening up a defect/enhancement request with kotlin. This does seem to be inappropriate behavior. I understand the reasoning for doing it but it should not be the default behavior imho.

Comment: Changing the behavior of toString() for data classes would be a backwards incompatible change, so it's very unlikely that we (the Kotlin team) are going to do it.

Comment: @miensol How can I access the property with reflection?

Comment: @luke `PhoneNumber::class.memberProperties.single { it.name == "lineNumber" }.let { it.isAccessible = true; it.get(phoneNumber) }`

Comment: @yole, yes it is but at the same time my understanding is that there are numerous enhancements coming to the data class in the future versions of kotlin. *if* ever an opportunity comes where backward compatibility is broken for the greater benefit then this one could also slip in along side with it.

Comment: I'm not aware of any planned enhancements to data classes that would break backward compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why Kotlin allows private properties in data class constructors but it seems to me that for a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), "a class to do nothing but hold data", you would want all of the data properties to be public and to be used in `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `toString()`, [`componentN()` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html), and `copy()`.

If this is not the case then I wouldn't call such a class a "data class" and `equals()`, `hashCode()`, etc. should be explicitly implemented.

Comment: There are a number of scenarios  where one would have a data class with portions of the information being "private". Just think about anything involving PCI/PII compliance (cvv, passwords, etc...). I think this should be filed as a defect/enhancement request to kotlin to remove the private values from the toString(). It has a bad smell to it.

Comment: @Ryba, CVV numbers, passwords, SSNs, and other sensitive information should not be stored in RAM longer than necessary. Salts and hashes should be used for authentication/comparison/lookup/etc. and not the raw data. Such sensitive information should also be stored using char arrays instead of `String` (http://security.stackexchange.com/q/73637). This would also result in a more appropriate string representation: `PhoneNumber(prefix=0676, lineNumber=[C@610455d6)` although I would still challenge the appropriateness of placing such information in a _data class_.

Comment: While all true, you have to concede that there is a point in time that it comes into the system as raw info. Just think about any kind of Http Request POJO. To get the information in, it is sent to the server unsalted, unencrypted, etc ... It is sitting inside of a data bean by definition for exactly the purpose it should. The data bean should have a getter that returns the salted/hashed version of things yes. But that is also exactly why the private variable that it is saved inside of should not be exposed in a toString() for example.

Comment: I would love to resist further but yes, such private information must be in memory at some point in time. However I still don't think you would want `equals()` or `hashCode()` on a POJO containing such information so one could simply not mark such a POJO with `data`.